# CakePHP 3 - Creating hiddenField

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

According with the documentation

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs

I use "HiddenField" to create a hidden input with value 0.. Like this

```
 echo $this->Form->Label("Stats ");            
                echo $this->Form->checkbox('stats', [
                                'value' => '1',
                                'hiddenField' => '0',
                            ]);
```

My HTML (there is no hidden field) as it should:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stats" value="1" required="required">
```

I did it yesterday, but today it's not working and i have not updated the cake version.. NOTHING, Crazy :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it wrong according to syntax .

Use following that I tested on localhost:

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('stats',array(
                                'value' => '1',
                                'hiddenField' => true,
                            ));
```

Your issue : `hiddenField' => '0',` What you did is you set it to 0 , so in PHP it typecasts to false (datatype conversion in PHP) . So make it true.

My output :

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[CourseCategory][stats]" id="CourseCategoryStats_" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[CourseCategory][stats]" value="1" id="CourseCategoryStats">
```

Comment: that's right, but i thought "array()" were sintax of cakephp 2.x! Well Thx ^^

Answer (score -1):

Use for value =0
echo $this->Form->checkbox('done');